# Python error "NetworkError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: python, ssh, openssl

**How it broke**

While troubleshooting my command line trying to `ssh root@ip` into Docker, I seem to I have messed up with `openssl`, somehow.

I can now connect to Docker, but I no longer can run scripts which require `requests`.

**1st attempt**

At first I did not know what was wrong.

If I ran `script.py`, it would just halt and fail silently.

**2nd attempt**

Then I tried to run the same script from within a `conda` `env`, which has `openssl` installed, and this time error was verbose, ending with:

```
NetworkError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

**openssl upgrade**

I have then tried to upgrade it system-wide with `brew upgrade openssl`, after which I got the following Caveats:

```
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
```

and I did it.

my `.ssh/` has:

```
github_rsa
github_rsa.pub
id_boot2docker
id_boot2docker.pub
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
```

Comment: SSH into a docker container? What about the good old `docker exec -ti container_name /bin/bash`?

Comment: will take note, thanks. but accessing docker is not the issue here. I neeed to run simple scripts with requests.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a library called `billboard.py`, being imported.

this import was causing the problem and halting the program, and the reason needs further investigation.

verbose Error was because conda env did not have all requeriments to run the program.